# How to get data from a table even when count(row) is zero? please see the description for more details and the query?

Tags: mysql, sql

table one

```
id   mandal_name
1    mandal1
2    mandal2
3    mandal3
```

table address

```
id   mandal_name   date
1    mandal1       2017-07-11 12:34:11
2    mandal1       2017-07-11 12:54:45
3    mandal1      2017-07-11 12:23:23
```

```sql
SELECT count(id) as yesterday_count, mandal FROM address WHERE date(date) = '2017-07-11'
```

Result obviously

```
3 , mandal1
```

Expecting result

```
3 , mandal1
0 , mandal2
0 , mandal3
...
```

Comment: Post the schema and a sample dataset that corresponds to the desired output

Comment: I edited the question @peterm. thank you

Comment: join your tables,get the list from table 1, then count it on table 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to use an `OUTER JOIN` - `LEFT JOIN` in this case.

You can either do

```sql
SELECT m.mandal_name, COUNT(a.id) AS yesterday_count
  FROM  table_one m LEFT JOIN address a 
    ON m.mandal_name = a.mandal_name
   AND a.date >= '2017-07-11'
   AND a.date < '2017-07-12'
 GROUP BY m.mandal_name;
```

or

```sql
SELECT m.mandal_name, COALESCE(count, 0) AS yesterday_count
  FROM  table_one m LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT mandal_name, COUNT(*) AS count 
      FROM address
     WHERE date >= '2017-07-11'
       AND date < '2017-07-12'
  ) a 
    ON m.mandal_name = a.mandal_name;
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6eb60/11) demo

Output

```
| mandal_name | yesterday_count |
|-------------|-----------------|
|     mandal1 |               3 |
|     mandal2 |               0 |
|     mandal3 |               0 |
```

Further reading - [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

On a side note - don't use `DATE(date)` as it makes it impossible to use an index on `date` column effectively causing a full table scan.

Comment: Hello, Peterm I need one more help, in the above query we are getting count only for one date, similarly, I want to find for last week and last month within the same query.

Answer (score 0):

you can query it like this:

```
SELECT A.mandal_name,IFNULL(COUNT(*),0)
FROM one A
LEFT JOIN address B ON A.mandal_name = B.mandal_name
WHERE DATE(B.date) = '2017-07-11'
GROUP BY A.mandal_name
```

just substitute your table name and columns to get the result

Comment: thanks, Leo I tried this query I am getting the same result.